# How are MPI processes started?

Tags: mpi

When starting an MPI job with `mpirun` or `mpiexec`, I can understand how one might go about starting each individual process. However, without any compiler magic, how do these  wrapper executables communicate the arrangement (MPI communicator) to the MPI processes?

I am interested in the details, or a pointer on where to look.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Details on how individual processes establish the MPI universe are implementation specific. You should look into the source code of the specific library in order to understand how it works. There are two almost universal approaches though:

- command line arguments: the MPI launcher can pass arguments to the spawned processes indicating how and where to connect in order to establish the universe. That's why MPI has to be initialised by calling `MPI_Init()` with `argc` and `argv` in C - thus the library can get access to the command line and extract all arguments that are meant for it;
- environment variables: the MPI launcher can set specific environment variables whose content can indicate where and how to connect.

Open MPI for example sets environment variables and also writes some universe state in a disk location known to all processes that run on the same node. You can easily see the special variables that its run-time component ORTE (OpenMPI Run-Time Environment) uses by executing a command like `mpirun -np 1 printenv`:

```
$ mpiexec -np 1 printenv | grep OMPI
... <many more> ...
OMPI_MCA_orte_hnp_uri=1660944384.0;tcp://x.y.z.t:43276;tcp://p.q.r.f:43276
OMPI_MCA_orte_local_daemon_uri=1660944384.1;tcp://x.y.z.t:36541
... <many more> ...
```

(IPs changed for security reasons)

Once a child process is launched remotely and `MPI_Init()` or `MPI_Init_thread()` is called, ORTE kicks in and reads those environment variables. Then it connects back to the specified network address with the "home" `mpirun`/`mpiexec` process which then coordinates all spawned processes into establishing the MPI universe.

Other MPI implementations work in a similar fashion.

Comment: Excellent response, thanks! I thought of environment variables as a possibility but could not find confirmation.