# Can MPI_Publish_name be used for two separately started applications?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I write an OpenMPI application which consists of a server and a client part which are launched separately:

```
me@server1:~> mpirun server
```

and

```
me@server2:~> mpirun client
```

`server` creates a port using `MPI_Open_port`. The question is: Does OpenMPI have a mechanism to communicate the port to `client`? I suppose that `MPI_Publish_name` and `MPI_Lookup_name` doesn't work here because `server` wouldn't know to which other computer the information should be sent.

To me, it looks like only processes which were started using a single `mpirun` can communicate with `MPI_Publish_name`.

I also found [ompi-server](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.4/man1/ompi-server.1.php), but the documentation is too minimalistic for me to understand this. Does anyone know how this is used?

Related: [MPICH: How to publish_name such that a client application can lookup_name it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210558/mpich-how-to-publish-name-such-that-a-client-application-can-lookup-name-it) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263458/client-server-example-using-ompi-does-not-work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MPI_Publish_name` is supplied with an MPI info object, which could have an Open MPI specific boolean key `ompi_global_scope`. If this key is set to true, then the name would be published to the global scope, i.e. to an already running instance of `ompi-server`. `MPI_Lookup_name` by default first does a global name lookup if the URI of the `ompi-server` was provided.

### With a dedicated Open MPI server

The process involves several steps:

1) Start the `ompi-server` somewhere in the cluster where it could be accessed from all nodes. For debugging purposes you may pass it the `--no-daemonize -r +` argument. It would start and print to the standard output an URI similar to this one:

```
$ ompi-server --no-daemonize -r +
1221656576.0;tcp://10.1.13.164:36351;tcp://192.168.221.41:36351
```

2) In the server, build an MPI info object and set the `ompi_global_scope` key to true:

```c
MPI_Info info;

MPI_Info_create(&info);
MPI_Info_set(info, "ompi_global_scope", "true");
```

Then pass the info object to `MPI_Publish_name`:

```c
MPI_Publish_name("server", info, port_name);
```

3) In the client, the call to `MPI_Lookup_name` would automatically do the lookup in the global context first (this could be changed by providing the proper key in the MPI info object, but in your case the default behaviour should suffice).

In order for both client and server code to know where the `ompi-server` is located, you have to give its URI to both `mpirun` commands with the `--ompi-server 1221656576.0;tcp://10.1.13.164:36351;tcp://192.168.221.41:36351` option.

Another option is to have `ompi-server` write the URI to a file, which can then be read on the node(s) where `mpirun` is to be run. For example, if you start the server on the same node where both `mpirun` commands are executed, then you could use a file in `/tmp`. If you start the `ompi-server` on a different node, then a shared file system (NFS, Lustre, etc.) would do. Either way, the set of commands would be:

```
$ ompi-server [--no-daemonize] -r file:/path/to/urifile
...
$ mpirun --ompi-server file:/path/to/urifile server
...
$ mpirun --ompi-server file:/path/to/urifile client
```

### Serverless method

If run both `mpirun`'s on the same node, the `--ompi-server` could also specify the PID of an already running `mpirun` instance to be used as a name server. It allows you to use local name publishing in the server (i.e. skip the "run an ompi-server" and "make an info object" parts). The sequence of commands would be:

```
head-node$ mpirun --report-pid server
[ note the PID of this mpirun instance ]
...
head-node$ mpirun --ompi-server pid:12345 client
```

where `12345` should be replaced by the real PID of the server's `mpirun`.

You can also have the server's `mpirun` print its URI and pass that URI to the client's `mpirun`:

```
$ mpirun --report-uri + server
[ note the URI ]
...
$ mpirun --ompi-server URI client
```

You could also have the URI written to a file if you specify `/path/to/file` (note: no `file:` prefix here) instead of `+` after the `--report-uri` option:

```
$ mpirun --report-uri /path/to/urifile server
...
$ mpirun --ompi-server file:/path/to/urifile client
```

Note that the URI returned by `mpirun` has the same format as that of an `ompi-server`, i.e. it includes the host IP address, so it also works if the second `mpirun` is executed on a different node, which is able to talk to the first node via TCP/IP (and `/path/to/urifile` lives on a shared file system).

I tested all of the above with Open MPI 1.6.1. Some of the variant might not work with earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer. Do you by any chance also know how the float number at the beginning of the URI/port_name comes about? I only found http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node214.htm, but it's again not very helpful. If you convert the number to hexadecimal, the first four digits are all zero... there can't be much information in there.

Comment: Ports names are implementation specific and URIs are very Open MPI specific. Comments in the source of the `rml` MCA component of OpenRTE indicate that URIs start with "process name". Further digging into the [name utility functions](https://svn.open-mpi.org/trac/ompi/browser/trunk/orte/util/name_fns.c) of ORTE shows that process names are concatenations of two unsigned longs in the form `<jobid>.<vpid>`.

Comment: I also did some digging, but I didn't come nearly as far as you. I compared the "left" unsigned long with the process id - they don't match, but they are close (e.g. 12551 and 13225). This is very weird.

Comment: The initial job ID is computed in [orte_plm_base_set_hnp_name()](https://svn.open-mpi.org/trac/ompi/browser/trunk/orte/mca/plm/base/plm_base_jobid.c#L37) in the `base` component of the PLM (process lifecycle management) framework. Apparently the value is based on the PID of the launcher and the hashed hostname.

Comment: Thank you for digging this up. They obviously want to make it absolutely necessary to communicate this string before the MPI stuff starts. I honestly don't see why one can't fix these address(es).

Comment: I guess that's the price one has to pay in order to have the full MPI-2 process management functionality.

Comment: I am using DeinoMPI and it seems that they do not support "--report-uri" argument. Is there any other way to let the client know of the address through which it should look up the port name?

Comment: @Z0lenDer, DeinoMPI is based on MPICH and not on Open MPI. You should probably consult the DeinoMPI manual.