# Is it possible to run OpenMPI on a local computer AND a remote cluster?

Tags: openmpi

I have a set of computational operations that need to be performed a cluster (maybe like 512 MPI processes).  Right now, I have the root node on the cluster open a socket and transfer data to my local computer in between the compute operations, but I'm wondering if it's possible to just create two MPI groups, and one of those groups is my local machine, and the other the remote cluster, and to send data between them using MPI commands.

Is this possible?

Comment: I see no reason why not, except practical configuration issues, with NAT, proxies, security, passphrases, encryption, firewall, open/closed ports etc... if you're in the same local network (and really the same, like only switches between your machine and the cluster, and no router) that should be fine. Your next problem is configure the mpi launch system and the nodes on your local machine to be recognized by the mpi launcher. (you need root access on the conf file of your cluster). But yeah MPI is made for heterogeneous parcs, so...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, as long as there is a network path between the cluster node and your machine. The MPI standard provides the abstract mechanisms to do it, while Open MPI provides a really simple way to make the things work. You have to look into the *Process Creation and Management* section of the standard (Chapter 10 of MPI-2.2), and specifically into the *Establishing Communication* subsection (§10.4 of MPI-2.2). Basically the steps are:

1. You start both MPI jobs separately. This is obviously what you do, so nothing new here.
2. One of the jobs creates a network port using `MPI_Open_port()`. This MPI call returns a unique port name that then has to be published as a well-known service name using `MPI_Publish_name()`. Once the port is opened, it can be used to accept client connections by calling the blocking routine `MPI_Comm_accept()`. The job has now become the server job.
3. The other MPI job, referred to as the client job, first resolves the port name from the service name using `MPI_Lookup_name()`. Once it has the port name, it can call `MPI_Comm_connect()` in order to connect to the remote server.
4. Once `MPI_Comm_connect()` is paired with the respective `MPI_Comm_accept()`, both jobs will establish an intercommunicator between them and messages could then be sent back and forth.

One intricate detail is how the client job could look up the port name given the service name? This is a less documented part of Open MPI, but it is quite easy: you have to provide the `mpiexec` command that you use to start the client job with the URI of the `mpiexec` of the server job, which acts as a sort of directory service. To do that, you should launch the server job with the `--report-uri -` argument to make it print its URI to the standard output:

```
$ mpiexec --report-uri - <other arguments like -np> ./server ...
```

It will give you a long URI of the form `1221656576.0;tcp://10.1.13.164:36351;tcp://192.168.221.41:36351`. Now you have to supply this URI to the client `mpiexec` with the `--ompi-server uri` option:

```
$ mpiexec --ompi-server 1221656576.0;tcp://10.1.13.164:36351... ./client ...
```

Note that the URI contains the addresses of all configured and enabled network interfaces that are present at the node, where the server's `mpiexec` is started. You should ensure that the client is able to reach at least one of them. Also ensure that you have the TCP BTL component in the list of enabled BTL components, otherwise no messages could flow. The TCP BTL is usually enabled by default, but on some InfiniBand installations it is explicitly disabled, either by setting the corresponding value of the environment variable `OMPI_MCA_btl` or in the default Open MPI MCA configuration file. The MCA parameters can be overridden with `--mca` option, for example:

```
$ mpiexec --mca btl self,sm,openib,tcp --report-uri - ...
```

Also see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008715/1374437) that I gave to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should just work out of the box if there is a TCP/IP connection available (MPI communicates at a random, high TCP port - if TCP is used as transfer layer). Try adding your machine to the hostfile which you supply to `mpirun`. If that doesn't work, you can directly connect to your machine using [MPI_Open_port](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Open_port.html) which doesn't require `mpirun`.