# Can I link two separate executables with MPI_open_port and share port information in a text file?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to create a shared `MPI COMM` between two executables which are both started independently, e.g.

```
mpiexec -n 1 ./exe1 
mpiexec -n 1 ./exe2
```

I use `MPI_Open_port` to generate port details and write these to a file in exe1 and then read with exe2. This is followed by `MPI_Comm_connect`/`MPI_Comm_accept` and then send/recv communication (minimal example below).

My question is: can we write port information to file in this way, or is the `MPI_Publish_name/MPI_Lookup_name` required for MPI to work as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007164/can-mpi-publish-name-be-used-for-two-separately-started-applications), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939757/is-it-possible-to-run-openmpi-on-a-local-computer-and-a-remote-cluster?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007164/can-mpi-publish-name-be-used-for-two-separately-started-applications?rq=1)? As supercomputers usually share a file system, this file based approach seems simpler and maybe avoids establishing a server.

It seems this should work according to the `MPI_Open_Port` documentation in the [MPI 3.1 standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf#page=419),

> port_name is essentially a network address. It is unique within the  communication universe to which it belongs (determined by the implementation), and may be used by any client within that communication universe. For instance,  if it is an  internet (host:port) address, it will be unique on the internet.  If it is a low level switch address on an IBM SP, it will be unique to that SP

In addition, according to documentation on the [MPI forum](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node213.htm#Node213):

- > The following should be compatible with MPI: The server prints out an address to the terminal, the user gives this address to the client program.
- > MPI does not require a nameserver
- > A port_name is a system-supplied string that encodes a low-level network address at which a server can be contacted.
- > By itself, the port_name mechanism is completely portable ...

Writing the port information to file does work as expected, i.e creates a shared communicator and exchanges information using MPICH (3.2) but hangs at the `MPI_Comm_connect`/`MPI_Comm_accept` line when using OpenMPI versions 2.0.1 and 4.0.1 (on my local workstation running Ubuntu 12.04 but eventually needs to work on a tier 1 supercomputer). I have raised as an [issue here](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/6878) but welcome a solution or workaround in the meantime.

### Further Information

If I use the MPMD mode with OpenMPI,

```
mpiexec -n 1 ./exe1 : -n 1 ./exe2
```

this works correctly, so must be an issue with allowing the jobs to share `ompi_global_scope` as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007164/can-mpi-publish-name-be-used-for-two-separately-started-applications) question. I've also tried adding,

```
MPI_Info info;
MPI_Info_create(&info);
MPI_Info_set(info, "ompi_global_scope", "true");
```

with info passed to all commands, with no success. I'm not running a server/client model as both codes run simultaneously so sharing a URL/PID from one is not ideal, although I cannot get this to work even using the suggested approach, which for OpenMPI 2.0.1,

```
mpirun -n 1 --report-pid + ./OpenMPI_2.0.1 0
1234

mpirun -n 1 --ompi-server pid:1234 ./OpenMPI_2.0.1 1
```

gives,

```
ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file base/rml_base_contact.c at line 161

This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  pmix server init failed
  --> Returned value Bad parameter (-5) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
```

and with OpenMPI 4.0.1,

```
mpirun -n 1 --report-pid + ./OpenMPI_4.0.1 0
1234

mpirun -n 1 --ompi-server pid:1234 ./OpenMPI_4.0.1 1
```

gives,

```
ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Bad parameter in file base/rml_base_contact.c at line 50

...

A publish/lookup server was provided, but we were unable to connect
to it - please check the connection info and ensure the server
is alive:
```

Using 4.0.1 means the error should not be related to [this](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/3458) bug in OpenMPI.

### Minimal code

```cpp
    #include "mpi.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
        int num_errors = 0;
        int rank, size;
        char port1[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];
        char port2[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Comm comm1, comm2;
        int data = 0;

        char *ptr;
        int runno = strtol(argv[1], &ptr, 10);
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
            printf("inputs %d %d %s \n", i,runno, argv[i]);

        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

        if (runno == 0)
        {
            printf("0: opening ports.\n");fflush(stdout);
            MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port1);
            printf("opened port1: <%s>\n", port1);

            //Write port file
            ofstream myfile;
            myfile.open("port");
            if( !myfile )
                    cout << "Opening file failed" << endl;
            myfile << port1 << endl;
            if( !myfile )
                cout << "Write failed" << endl;
            myfile.close();

            printf("Port %s written to file \n", port1); fflush(stdout);

            printf("Attempt to accept port1.\n");fflush(stdout);

            //Establish connection and send data
            MPI_Comm_accept(port1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm1);

            printf("sending 5 \n");fflush(stdout);
            data = 5;
            MPI_Send(&data, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, comm1);
            MPI_Close_port(port1);
        }
        else if (runno == 1)
        {

            //Read port file
            size_t   chars_read = 0;  
            ifstream myfile;
            //Wait until file exists and is avaialble
            myfile.open("port");
            while(!myfile){
                myfile.open("port");
                cout << "Opening file failed" << myfile << endl;
                usleep(30000);
            }
            while( myfile && chars_read < 255 ) {
                myfile >> port1[ chars_read ];    
                if( myfile ) 
                     ++chars_read; 

                if( port1[ chars_read - 1 ] == '\n' ) 
                     break;
            }
            printf("Reading port %s from file \n", port1); fflush(stdout);
            remove( "port" );

            //Establish connection and recieve data
            MPI_Comm_connect(port1, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm1);
            MPI_Recv(&data, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, comm1, &status);
            printf("Received %d 1\n", data); fflush(stdout);

        }

        //Barrier on intercomm before disconnecting
        MPI_Barrier(comm1);
        MPI_Comm_disconnect(&comm1);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
```

The 0 and 1 simply specify if this code writes a port file or reads it in the example above. This is then run with,

```
mpiexec -n 1 ./a.out 0 
mpiexec -n 1 ./a.out 1
```

Comment: This is an issue you’d rather report to the Open MPI mailing list, or open an issue at https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, thank you for the suggestion, although I'm not sure it's a bug or a feature request for OpenMPI, I want to know if MPI would be expected to work using a port written in this way (interestingly someone has posted a similar issue today https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/6818, maybe related to this question).

Comment: After no answers, I've assumed it is a bug/issue and raised on OpenMPI repo (https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/6878)

Comment: Just noting here that this approach works for me with MPICH. I don't have much experience with OpenMPI.