# MPI Client fails at looking up Server port (MPI_ERR_NAME: invalid name argument)

Tags: c++, linux, mpi, openmpi

I'm currently trying to setup a MPI-Client connecting to a server which publishes a certain name but it doesn't work and I have no clue about it.

*MPI is OpenMPI 1.6 using g++-4.7,* where /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/etc/openmpi-default-hostfile contains 1 line:

```
MY_IP
```

The following "minimal" (I don't like questions using too much code but I think I should include it here) example illustrates the problem:

### mpi_srv.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (void)
{

  int rank(0);
  MPI_Init(0, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  std::cout << "Rank: " << rank << std::endl;
  char port_name[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];
  MPI_Open_port(MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name);
  char publish_name[1024] = {'t','e','s','t','_','p','o','r','t','\0'};
  MPI_Publish_name(publish_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name);
  std::cout << "Port: " << publish_name << " (" << port_name << ")" << std::endl;
  MPI_Comm client;
  std::cout << "Wating for Comm..." << std::endl;
  MPI_Comm_accept(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &client);
  std::cout << "Comm accepted" << std::endl;
  MPI_Comm_free(&client);
  MPI_Unpublish_name(publish_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name);
  MPI_Close_port(port_name);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 1;

}
```

compiled and executed via

```
mpic++ mpi_src.cc -o mpi_srv.x
mpirun mpi_srv.x
```

prints

```
Rank: 1
Port: test_port (2428436480.0;tcp://MY_IP:33573+2428436481.0;tcp://MY_IP:43172:300)
Wating for Comm...
```

and blocks as required.

My client

### mpi_client.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (void)
{

  int rank(0);
  MPI_Init(0, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  std::cout << "Rank: " << rank << std::endl;
  char port_name[MPI_MAX_PORT_NAME];
  char publish_name[1024] = {'t','e','s','t','_','p','o','r','t','\0'};
  MPI_Lookup_name(publish_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, port_name);
  MPI_Comm client;
  MPI_Comm_connect(port_name, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &client);
  MPI_Comm_disconnect(&client);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 1;

}
```

compiled and executed via

```
mpic++ mpi_client.cc -o mpi_client.x
mpirun mpi_client.x
```

prints

```
Rank: 1
[MY_HOST:24870] *** An error occurred in MPI_Lookup_name
[MY_HOST:24870] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[MY_HOST:24870] *** MPI_ERR_NAME: invalid name argument
[MY_HOST:24870] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
```

with the server still running.

I removed the error checking in the exmaples above but the function return values indicate successful publication of the port name in the server executable.
I found out that this problem can arise because of the published port being invisible to the client when using different mpirun but I used the same mpirun executable to execute both.

Why doesn't the client connect to the server as I'd expect here?

Comment: Sorry, how did you removed the error? I'm having exactly the same error, and don´t know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run two separate MPI sessions, e.g.:

```
$ mpirun mpi_server.x
...
```

and

```
$ mpirun mpi_client.x
...
```

the second (client) MPI session has to be told where the naming service that holds the name/port mapping is located. With Open MPI you have several choices of naming service:

- an instance of the dedicated naming service daemon `ompi-server`, or
- the `mpirun` process of the server session.

In both cases the client session has to be provided with the location of the naming service. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007164/can-mpi-publish-name-be-used-for-two-separately-started-applications) and my answer to it for more information on how to deal with this in Open MPI.

Answer (score 2):

Name publishing is a tricky thing and can behave a little differently from one implementation to the next. It's up to the implementation to decide what level of support it will provide. For Open MPI (https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Publish_name.3.php), it appears that you can set an `MPI_Info` key to specify that the name should be published locally or globally. You should make sure that you're publishing globally if you won't be starting your clients via `MPI_Comm_spawn` (which you're not).

Beyond that, this isn't a feature that I've used a lot so it may be that there's something else going on here.