# Ncurses limited output size

Tags: c++, terminal, ncurses, curses

I'm learning how to use ncurses and I'm in a weird situation.
It seems my output can't go over 24 lines.
Moreover, whenever I run my software, and the execution finishes his job, my terminal stops working as before, and I have 2 different situations:

- if I've launched my run from a line behind line 24 I can use the terminal, but if I keep scrolling when at the last line of the window, nothing more happens: all input and output keep happening in the last line, without any new line appearing at enter pressure.
- if I've launched the run above line 24 the terminal will only become 24-lines high.

Both situations require me to reset the terminal, then everything works again.
I'm on  MAC OSX machine.

Comment: You don't plan on sharing any code?

Comment: Without sample code (which we can test), we can offer only generic advice.

Comment: I'll produce a sample code to simulate my issues. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the screen-size:

- The easiest one to see is if you has `LINES` environment variable set to 24.  The [`use_env`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html) manpage gives some clues about that.
- The reason why it sounds like a problem with screen-size is that the description of the problem suggests that the program is setting the scrolling region to 24 lines.
- If there is no problem with `LINES`, then a place to check is by running `stty -a` to see what the operating system supposes the screen-size to be.  That is reported on the first line of `stty`'s output as "rows".
- In some cases (for instance in remote network connections), it is possible to have a session where the remote host cannot obtain the screen-size.  As a workaround, you could run the [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program (an xterm utility) to update the operating system's notion of the screen-size.

By the way, your other question [NCurses not restoring terminal behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165104/ncurses-not-restoring-terminal-behavior) appears to be a duplicate of this.  You should consolidate your questions into a single one which provides enough information for someone to offer useful information about the problem.

Comment: Hello again,

thanks for your suggestion. stty -a correctly gives me 67x278 lines.
I'm trying to find out something with your suggestions.
I'll report later on.

Have fun

gf